# How to define a reply-to address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

How can I define a reply-to address different than the `:from` one? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Two ways:

```
class Notifications < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from     => 'your_app@your_domain.com',
          :reply_to => 'some_other_address@your_domain.com'
end
```

Or:

```
class Contacts < ActionMailer::Base
  def new_contact
    mail( :to       => 'somebody@some_domain.com',
          :from     => 'your_app@your_domain.com',
          :reply_to => 'someone_else@some_other_domain.com')
  end
end
```

Or you can mix the two approaches. I'm sure there are even more ways to do this.

Comment: Silly boy, I've looked everywhere but the mail method definition: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/mail
Thank you!

Comment: The official docs show this too: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail

Comment: According to this: https://www.igvita.com/2007/07/21/sendmail-spam-filter-tricks-in-rails/ they should match, or your mail will get flagged by spam software.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Rails 5.2 and possibly older/newer versions:

Amend the file:

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

With content:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {
      reply_to:             'test@example.com'
  }
end
```

The reference:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration